# Почему rootState.settingsModule.settings возвращает null?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

возник следующий вопрос по vuex: есть модуль indicatorsModule, из данного модуля нужно получить доступ к данным из другого модуля - settingsModule. Если в качестве значения `const settingsList` передать `rootState.settingsModule`, то в консоли легко увидеть, что в объекте `settingsModule` есть нужное свойство `settings`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если попытаться получить доступ к свойству `settings`, то в консоли будет `null`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом на вкладке Сеть легко увидеть, что запрос к settings уходит и успешно возвращает ответ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как избежать подобного поведения?

Comment: Держите в голове, что запрос - он асинхронный. Поправить это никак нельзя :) Пишите код с учетом того, что в settings может быть null.